# Where is "evt" defined in an HTML event handler

Tags: html, dom-events

I ran across some code like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="0 0 30 20"
 onload="console.log('hello', evt, this)">
```

**Can someone tell we where `evt` is defined and/or documented?**

When I run it I see that `evt` is defined to be the event object associated with the `onload` event.  And `this` points the SVG element.  Chrome's debugger tells me that `evt` and `this` are both local variables.

I tried https://www.google.com/search?q=html+event+handler+evt and several variations on that theme.
All I've learned from there is that `evt`, `e`, and `event` are commonly used as the name of a parameter inside of an event handler function.
But this `evt` is created by Chrome, and if I change my sample code to say `e` I will get an undefined variable and a reference error in the console.

Thanks!

**edit**

I've been poking around a little more.  The Chrome debugger shows me this.  Chrome added `onLoad(evt) {` and `}` all on its own.  It wrapped that function around the code I gave it.  Interesting.

[image]

Comment: Only thing about SVG specs I can find where there is any true discussion around `evt` is [here](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2006Apr/0117.html) from 2006. You can scroll to the bottom and click next message over and over to read about the history. It's definitely something that SVG implemented explicitly at some point and maybe still? I only made it about 10 messages in but it's pretty interesting and there may be some jewels of knowledge in there to further your understanding.